Read dynamic Secret from Azure Key Vault in BotController.cs
I am generating Direct Line token in my application and pushing it to the Key Vault. The BotController.cs reads the token based on username. Currently, I have hard coded the username but I want to make it dynamic. FYI, I am passing username as a parameter in the URL as well. Return "https://bot-app-service.azurewebsites.net?username=" + UserName
Could you please help me achieve this? Below is the code, see GetBotTokenFromKeyVault method. Thanks a lot.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using System;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Controllers
{
    [Route("api")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BotController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
        private readonly IBot _bot;
        private readonly string _botToken;  // Token injected from Startup

        // Dependency injection to receive the bot token
        public BotController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IBot bot, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _adapter = adapter;
            _bot = bot;

            // Fetch the bot token from Azure Key Vault
            _botToken = GetBotTokenFromKeyVault(configuration);
        }

        [HttpPost, HttpGet, Route("messages")]
        public async Task PostAsync()
        {
            // Processes the incoming request using the bot framework adapter
            await _adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, _bot);
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("token")]
        public IActionResult GetToken()
        {
            // Returns the bot token fetched from Azure Key Vault
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_botToken))
            {
                return Ok(new { token = _botToken });
            }
            else
            {
                return NotFound("Token not found");
            }
        }

        // Method to fetch bot token from Azure Key Vault
        private string GetBotTokenFromKeyVault(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var keyVaultEndpoint = "https://bot-keyvault.vault.azure.net/";
            var secretName = "BTsid";  //should be BT{username}
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultEndpoint), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            var secret = client.GetSecret(secretName);

            return secret.Value.Value;
        }
    }
}

